# Why does the icon get changed/destroyed when enlarging+downsizing?

Tags: image, image-processing, png, jpeg, paint

[original_Icon](http://www.iconj.com/ico/6/z/6z5wjqzcgb.ico)

Why do the pixxels get changed when I enlarge and then downsize it properly in windows paint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not a scalable vector graphic but a raster image. Rescaling images requires adding or removing/leaving pixels unless you scale with integer factors.

Simple example:  Imagine a 2 pixel image, one black, one white image `BW`

Now how do you downsize its width by 50% ?  Do you remove the black pixel? Or the white one? Or do you calculate their average as the new value of that single pixel?

Now double that single pixels size. No matter which value you chose for that remaining pixel, you'll never get `BW` back. You'll end up with `BB`, `WW` or `GG` and there is now way to tell if that was the original image.

Unless you're using integer scale factors you'll always generate some new information or loose some.

Comment: thanks, very clear and easy to understand answer=)